# Jquery - Add a property to an input field when some criteria match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this is possible to do with Jquery/Javascript.

The case:

I have a hidden input field and a select field, I need to add 'value="1"' to the hidden input field when I select an option with the value >= 1 on the select field.

```
<input id="id-1-biketype" type="hidden" name="1-biketype">
<select id="id-1-units" name="1-units">
    <option selected="selected" value="">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="999">+20</option>
</select>
```

So that the hidden input looks like this:

```
<input id="id-1-biketype" type="hidden" name="1-biketype" value="1">
```

Any clues on how to do this and if it is possible?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here's a jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WhsL4/3/)

Use the `change()` event on the select, and `val()` to set the value on the input:

```
$('#id-1-units').change(function(){
    if(this.value >= 1) {
      $('#id-1-biketype').val("1"); 
      // Greater than or equal to one - set the value property to 1 on the input
    }
    else {
      $('#id-1-biketype').val("");
      // Less than one - remove the 1 value from the input.
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 but just a little thing, $('#id-1-biketype').val(1) is better than than $('#id-1-biketype').prop('value', '1'); to set/get the value as said in the jQuery doc (http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @RafH Updated, thanks. So used to using prop() I should probably try to remember selector performance more often!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the "else" completed what I need in the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are right, thanks ! Dont know why it said that its better to use val() to set values on jQuery doc (right here http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can do this:

```
$("#id-1-units").change(function() {
    if (this.value >= 1) {
        $("#id-1-biketype").attr("value", 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
$("#id-1-units").change(function() {
  $("#id-1-biketype").val($(this).val());
});
```